# Using SHUTIL to copy a file into a directory with a space in its name

Tags: python, shutil

I'm trying to build a program that will read in a list of files, add a prefix and a suffix to the filename, and then copy the file to a new folder with the new file name. So, for example, a file named "Reports.pdf" would become "PBC_Reports_V1.pdf"

The problem I have is when either the source or destination directory have a space in their name, the shutil module can't find the directory. I'm not sure what I need to do to have shutil recognize the directory, and could use some help.

code is as follows:

```
  ## This program is intended to allow a batch of files to have their name changed to standard IA formats
import os, shutil, datetime
from tkinter import *


strFolderName = "\Test"
#strNewPath = basePath+strFolderName

root = Tk()
root.title("Bulk File Renaming")
#root.iconbitmap(r"C:\Coding\FlagIcon.bmp")


############################################################################################################################################
## This section sets up the program's GUI. The buttons have to come after the modules, but this has to come at the beginning of the code
## because, of course, putting all the GUI stuff together would make too much sense. Oh well. GUI until the next line of hashtags.

strF = os.getcwd()           #Finds the current file path
strFileIn = StringVar()      #This is where we'll store the input path
strFileIn.set(strF)          #Puts the current directory in the box

strFileOut = StringVar()    #This variable is the output path
strFileOut.set(strF+r"\ConvertedFiles")

str1 = StringVar()           #This variable holds the radiobutton output, which represents the file prefix
str1.set("\PBC_")              #For some reason, if you try to set a variable in the same line you declare it, it stops working.

strPrefixes = [("PBC (Prepared by Client)", "\PBC_"),     #A list (tuple?) of the different prefixes and their meaning. 
            ("WP (Working Paper)", "\WP_"),               #To be called futher down when we create the radiobuttons
            ("COM (Communications)", "\COM_"),
            ("MIN (Minutes)", "\MIN_"),
            ("PM (Project Management)", "\PM_"),
            ("DOC (Anything not created by IA or the OPI)", "\DOC_")]

inRow = 5
inCol = 0
for strPref, val in strPrefixes:
    Radiobutton(root, text=strPref, variable=str1, value=val).grid(row =inRow, column=inCol, sticky=(W))
    inCol=inCol+1
    if inCol>2:
        inCol=0
        inRow=6


#First, labels
myLabelSource = Label(root, text="Source Folder").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(E))
myLabelDestn = Label(root, text="Destination Folder").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(E))
myLabelPrefix = Label(root, text="Select Desired Prefix").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=(W))

#Next, input boxes
#Source files' location
enSource = Entry(root, textvariable=strFileIn).grid(row=0, column = 1, columnspan=3, sticky=(W,E))
#Destination files' location
enDestn = Entry(root, textvariable=strFileOut).grid(row=1, column = 1, columnspan =3, sticky=(W,E))


#################################################################################################################################################

#This module shuts down the program
def progExit():
    root.quit()             #Closes all the program's stuff
    root.destroy()          #Actually shuts things down.



#This module gets the date the file was last modified
def getDate(strA):
# Depending on how the file was created/modified, the creation date may be placed in the date modified field and vice versa. 
# Here, we take both the modified and created date, see which one is earlier, format it in a YYYY-MM-DD format, and
# return it to the user.

    strC = os.path.getctime(strA)   #Gets the created date, as time since the epoch
    strB = os.path.getmtime(strA)   #Gets the modified date, as time since the epoch                       
    
    if strB<strC:
        strB = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(strB)        #Converts the date into a readable string
        strB = str(strB)
        strB=strB[0:10]                                     #Leaves just the YYYY-MM-DD fields
        return strB
    else:
        strC = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(strC)
        strC=str(strC)
        strC=strC[0:10]                                    
        return strC 



#This module determines the location of the '.' at the end of the filename, before the file type indicator.
def fileTypeLength(strName):    
    inI = len(strName)-1        #Since the first letter in the string is in the 0 position, we subtract 1 from the length to make the loop work
    while inI>-1:
        if strName[inI] == chr(46):     #The '.' char has an ascii value of 46. It's easier for python to understand what we're looking for this way.
            return inI
        else:
            inI=inI-1           #We go from the end towards the front so that if there are any '.' in the file name it won't screw up the program
        if inI<0:
            outputLabel=Label(root, text="Error finding file suffix for file "+strName).grid(row=8, column = 1)
            root.quit()
        

#This module is where the program actually copies the file, and pastes together everything else.
def copyAllFiles():   
    inA=0
    strPrefix=str1.get()
    strNewPath=os.path.abspath(strFileOut.get())
    strEntry=os.path.abspath(strFileIn.get())
    listOfFiles = os.listdir(strFileIn.get())
    if os.path.isdir(strNewPath) == False:
        os.mkdir(strNewPath)
    for entry in listOfFiles:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(strEntry, entry)):   # Verify that file in question is a file, not a folder
            entryEd=entry                                   # entryEd holds the file name
            entry=(os.path.join(strEntry, entry))           # entry holds the file location
            strDate = getDate(entry)                        # Gets the file's creation date
            inL = len(entryEd)
            inS = fileTypeLength(entryEd)                   #Finds the position of the '.' at the end of the file name
            strFT = entryEd[inS:inL]                        #Here we remove the file type idenifier, so that it can be moved to the end of the copied filename
            entryEd=entryEd[0:inS]                                
            strOutputFile = strNewPath+strPrefix+entryEd+"_"+str(strDate)+"_V1"+str(strFT)
            shutil.copy2(entry, strOutputFile)              #This copies the file, and all its attributes
            inA = inA+1
    outputLabel=Label(root, text=str(inA)+" files successfully processed").grid(row=8, column = 1)



##### These are the buttons that the GUI uses to launch the program or shut it down. 
buttonExit=Button(root, text="Click here to exit", padx=50, command=progExit).grid(row=7, column=2)
buttonProcess=Button(root,text="Rename Files", padx=50, command=copyAllFiles).grid(row=7, column=1)

#The last thing we have to do is name the GUI that we started building on line 9. Tkinter is a funny module. 
root.mainloop()
```

I can verify that the variables have two slashes for all the folder dividers, so `strOutputFile = C:\\Example Folder\\Example Output\\PBC_Reports_V1.pdf' .

Anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: The `shutil` module should cope fine. Are you sure these `get()` methods are returning valid paths, though? Can you please [edit] to provide a [mre] where no code is missing, so we don't have to guess about code we can't see?

Comment: @tripleee, yes, the get methods are returning valid paths. The program isn't very long, so I've just copied and pasted the entire thing into the OP. Thanks for the help!